# Plus sign, and percentage signs in .htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to apply a RewriteRule on a certain URL via .htaccess and I've encountered a problem.

Here is the code I had before for this specific usage:

```
RewriteRule ^levels-u-([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ levels.php?p=$1&i=u&r=true [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^levels-u-([a-z0-9_-]+)-\(([a-z]+)\)\.html$ levels.php?p=$1&i=u&n=$2&r=true [QSA,L,NC]
```

the way this worked is that there could be this page:

levels-u-username.html

or this page:

levels-u-username-(text).html

But the text for username was able to include spaces and brackets (which appeared as +, %5B, and %5D) as well.

So I used this code to match any combination of characters

```
RewriteRule ^levels-u-([^/]+)\.html$ levels.php?p=$1&i=u&r=true [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^levels-u-([^/]+)-\(([a-z]+)\)\.html$ levels.php?p=$1&i=u&n=$2&r=true [QSA,L,NC]
```

so that now, this will not output a 404 error:

levels-u-username+%5Bmore%5D.html    (which is "username [more]")

But now the problem, is that the latter

levels-u-username-(text).html

will rewrite "username-(deleted)" in the first RewriteRule as $1, as opposed to in the second with $1 = "username" and $2 = "text"

What I am trying to figure out, is how to incorporate plus signs and brackets into this regex for .htaccess mod_rewrite:

```
([a-z0-9_-]+)
```

because

```
([^/]+)
```

creates conflict with another RewriteRule.

Again, these are the characters I need added to the expression:

"+", "%5B" (which is "["), "%5D" (which is "]")

Another thought I had was disabling the phrase "-(" if possible?

Comment: turning on rewrite logs may help you to find what is going on and why...

Answer (score 0):

Just to support those additional characters you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^levels-u-([\[\]+\w]+)\.html$ index.php?p=$1&i=u&r=true [QSA,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^levels-u-([\[\]+\w]+)-\(([a-z]+)\)\.html$ levels.php?p=$1&i=u&n=$2&r=true [QSA,L,NE]
```